# POST http://localhost:8080/create 500 (Internal Server Error)5

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter

I always get "POST http://localhost:8080/create 500 (Internal Server Error)" when insert new data in ajax (CodeIgniter 4, Bootstrap 5). I've checked and replaced JQuery many times, and don't know what's wrong with my code. This is my javascript code (action.js) :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#save").on('submit',function(e){  
        e.preventDefault();
        const nama=$("#nama_id").val();
        const image=$("#file_id").val();
        const formdata=new FormData(this);
        if(nama == "" || image == "" ){  
            alert("Nama dan foto harus diisi");
        }
        else{  
            $.ajax({ 
                url:"/create",
                type:"POST",
                data:formdata,
                processData:false,
                contentType:false,
                success:(data)=>{
                    if(data == 1){  
                        alert("Tambah data sukses");
                    }else{  
                        alert("Tambah data gagal");
                    }
                }
            })
        }
    });
```

and this is the function inside controller code :

```
   public function simpan() {         
        $cv = $this->cvModel->getCV();
        $fileName = $this->request->getFile('file');
        if ($fileName->isValid() && ! $fileName->hasMoved()) {
            $newName = $fileName->getRandomName();
            $fileName->move("uploads/", $newName);
        }       
        $data = [
            'nama' => $cv->request->getVar('nama'),
            'pasfoto' => $newName,
        ];
        
        $simpan = $cv->save($data);
        if ($simpan) {
            echo 1;
        }else {
            echo 0;
        }
    }
```

When I inspect in Chrome it always stuck in row 27 (start ajax) like this :
[image]

Comment: What do your server-side logs say about the error?

Comment: change your url:"/create" to url:"/simpan"

Comment: I' ve changed the url to /simpan, but now it said "Call to a member function getRandomName() on null". I'm so sure the id of image file in view (index.php) is "file_id", like in action.js above...?

Comment: I assume you got a function name call getRandomName() , so just change to             $newName = getRandomName(); instead of  $newName = $fileName->getRandomName();

Comment: If I change to $newName = getRandomName(); then getRandomName will be red underlined by Intelephense and error "Call to undefined function App\Controllers\getRandomName()". It is okey (work fine) $newName = $fileName-> getRandomName();........., but another error "Call to a member function save() on array" rise now at row code : $simpan = $cv->save($data); , but thanks for your answer.

Comment: If a trace the values : dd($data), then it show exactly what I want ('nama' & 'pasfoto'), but why error show in $simpan = $cv->save($data), thanks again for your answer.

Answer (score -1):

you can try

url : base_url().'/class_name/methode_name';

Comment: base_url() is a CI method (php). You can't use it like this in the Ajax (javascript) function

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).